# Installing Numpy using pip3 on Ubuntu - Error “Command failed with exit status 1”

Tags: pip, numpy

I have installed pip3 on Ubuntu. But while using it to install numpy (using command 'pip3 install numpy') I am getting the following error -

```
error: Command "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.5/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.5/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.5m -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.5/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.5/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.5/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.5/numpy/core/src/npymath -c build/src.linux-x86_64-3.5/numpy/core/src/npysort/radixsort.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.5/numpy/core/src/npysort/radixsort.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.5/numpy/core/src/npysort/radixsort.o.d" failed with exit status 1
```

I couldn't find any answer to a similar error like this. Could anyone please help with the error?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find a [rather similar problem to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492878/command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1#42690573). In short:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev
```

I slightly changed the original answer to fit python3 (changed `python-dev` to `python3-dev`

Answer (score 2):

I stumpled upon this question while trying to install tensorflow on a raspberri pi. Since my error code looked similar but additionally had the following text:

> ```
> numpy/core/src/npysort/radixsort.c.src: In function ‘aradixsort_ulonglong’:
> numpy/core/src/npysort/radixsort.c.src:202:5: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
>      for (npy_intp i = 1; i < num; i++) {
>      ^
> error: Command "gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/home/pi/berryconda3/envs/tfcpu/include -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -fPIC -O2 -pipe -I/home/pi/berryconda3/envs/tfcpu/include -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -fPIC -O2 -pipe -fPIC -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/home/pi/berryconda3/envs/tfcpu/include/python3.6m -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath -c build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/radixsort.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.6/build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/radixsort.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.6/build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/radixsort.o.d" failed with exit status 1
> ```

With google I found the following Github discussion where I found the [answer](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14147#issuecomment-524065411). This is from the github answer - credit goes to [oolongtea](https://github.com/oolongtea):

```
CFLAGS=-std=c99 pip install numpy
```